# Why is it 'THE absence of something' but 'A lack of something'?

Tags: grammar, articles

In both cases, it's some specific absence/lack. Why should I use the definite article with the former and the indefinite article with the latter?

Comment: You can have ***an*** absence of something too, and ***the*** lack of something. Probably depends on context.

Comment: It's partly purely idiomatic. I would say *I have **a** lack of funds*, but I can't imagine ever saying *I have **the** lack of funds*, which sounds simply bizarre. Mainly, it's because *a lack of funds* is the phrase that's always used; whereas, in that particular sentence, *the lack of funds* is never used. (Despite the fact that,in reality, I actually would be referring to a specific and current state of lacking funds.) Anybody following rules of grammar would expect *the* to be used. But it isn't in this case. Because English is often illogical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, they **don't** mean the same:

- "Absence" *always* means that something is not there.
- "Lack" *can* mean that something is absent, but can also mean a shortage, or a deficiency.

Secondly, you **can** use either the definite or indefinite article with both words. [This example](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/absence) is in the Cambridge dictionary:

> The business was suffering from *an absence* of an overall plan for moving forward.

See also [this example](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lack) for "lack" with the definite article:

> The local residents were angry at *the lack* of parking spaces.

The use of either the definite or indefinite article is determined by whether or not you can point to a single lack or absence.

For example, if a shop received a delivery of cakes every day, but one day the delivery did not arrive, they might say they "have *a lack* of cakes". It isn't *the* lack, because it isn't the only lack of cakes - it may have happened before, it may happen again, and it may happen elsewhere. However, if you were speaking about *that* specific cake shop on *that* specific day, you might say "I'm annoyed about *the* lack* of cakes in *the* shop *today*". This is because you have identified a specific lack so the definite article is required.

Comment: Who said those mean the same?

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev You said "in both cases, it's some specific absence/lack" so I felt the need to be clear from the start they don't mean the same. You're comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: No, I'm not. I just said that both cases are — to me — specific because of the 'of' parts. The fact that they are semantically similar ("absence" is basically the same as "lack" but brought to the absolute, if it's a regular English) just emphasizes that it's not perfectly logical (at first sight, at least)

Comment: That Grammarly gizmo can't help underlining with red anything stat starts with 'an absence of'. So that's partly the reason why I asked this question

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev Asking questions here gets you answers from native English speakers like myself that ought to be more reliable than Grammarly, which is just highlighting *possible* errors.

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev Using "of" doesn't make it a specific "lack". Saying "a shortage of food" is the same as saying "a food shortage". There have been many food shortages around the world throughout history - "a shortage of food" could describe any of them. You'd have to be more specific, for example "*the* food shortage in Yemen" is specific because it gives the place.

Comment: But not time! You previously mentioned time!

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev There is a *current* food shortage in Yemen, so no need to include the time in that example as it would be assumed you referred to that. If you wanted to refer to a historical food shortage you could include the date, for example "*the* Dutch famine of 1944-1945"

Comment: So if I'm speaking about, for example, "investing in production of silicon" (generally, not in a particular place or at a particular time), I shouldn't use 'the', should I?